# Height 100% property won't work in css on bootstrap 3 in side navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bascially the side navbar when scrolling won't carry on for 100% in height and when you click on two ul's then of course there isn't enough of the sidebar so then the ul's disappear. 
I have added height:100%;
Have I misplaced a nav or div anywhere which is why the height isn't 100%?

```css
        .pdsa-sn-wrapper{
            position:absolute;
            top:3.6em;
            left:0em;
            width:13em;
            height:100%;
            background-color:#FF9900; /*orange.*/
            transition:left 0.3s linear;
            -moz-transition:left 0.3s linear;
            -webkit-transition:left 0.3s linear;
        }
        
        .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul {
            list-style:none;
            width:11em;
            margin-top:2em;
            margin-left:1em;
            padding:0em;
            
        }
```

```html
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <header>
            <a class="linkStyle" href="Default.html">My Tunes</a>
            </header>
            </div>
            <nav id="sideNavParent" class="pdsa-sn-wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li class="pdsa-sn-brand"><a href="Default.html" class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Music</a>
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                        <a href="default.html">
                            <span class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Home</span>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home visible-xs"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse"
                           data-target="#ulGenres" >
                            <span class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Genres&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></span>
                         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe visible-xs"></i>
                        </a>
                    <div class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                    <ul id="ulGenres" class="collapse" data-parent="#sideNavParent">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">All Genres</a>
                         </li> 
                         <li>
                         <a href="#">Jazz</a>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                             <a href="#">Country</a>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                             <a href="#">Rock</a>
                         </li>
                    </ul>
                   </div> 
                </li>
                   
                <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse"
                           data-target="#ulPlaylists">
                            <span class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Playlists&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></span>
                         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt visible-xs"></i>
                        </a>
                          <div class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                    <ul id="ulPlaylists" class="collapse" data-parent="#sideNavParent">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">All Playlists</a>
                         </li> 
                         <li>
                         <a href="#">My Top Rated</a>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                             <a href="#">Top Country</a>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                             <a href="#">Top Classic Rock</a>
                         </li>
                    </ul>
                   </div> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Songs</span>
                         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-music visible-xs"></i>
                    </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                         <span class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Downloads</span>
                         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download visible-xs"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: the nav is positioned absolutely, therefore it has no parent element to base it's 100% height off of. It's height will instead be the height of the viewport.

Comment: You are missing a closing `</div>` tag look [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qnrqe7zv/) .

Comment: The HTML is not valid. There are unclosed tags.

Comment: Am i missing something? the only unclosed tag i see is `<nav>`, because at the end `<nav>` and `<div>` are backwards. The missing closing li tags on the last list item in a ul is valid.

Comment: is there anything to correct that you guys can give a demo of in a fiddle? because the one by david domain isn't working when copied and pasted into the my website.

Comment: I stand corrected, it is working thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `height: 100vh` to make the nav 100% of the viewport. Find additional info [here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)...